# Add meta tags in User control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, meta-tags

How to add meta tags in User control??? I want to add rel="nofollow" attribute to all links in user control. 
How to add rel attribute to all links.
Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.ttt.com">MyLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

code behind:

```
this.MyLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "nofollow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add rel to markup, like this :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" rel="nofollow" NavigateUrl="http://www.url.com">url</asp:HyperLink>
```